# how to normalize my database

Tags: database, normalization

I have this table and I don't know how to normalize.

1st table
name, address, landline no., mobile no., e-mail ad, amount, and registration number
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2dDVLVHV4dU1yRFE/edit

and in the second table will be their monthly pledges. 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2TVh4c1dmLTFYOWs/edit

Comment: Normalization is about understanding your data.  Removing duplicate columns, removing records which would result in repeated data in a table. So if each data element associates to only that data element in a 1-to-1 relationship then having them in one table is ok, so long as the majority of the time each element will have data.  Normal form suggests that if it will not have data, separate it into its own table.... So.... What do you think is wrong/missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok to me.

If first table is User and the second is Pledge, then it looks like you have a one-to-many relationship between User and Pledge.  Both tables should have a primary key.  The Pledge table will have a foreign key to the User table, where the foreign key column will reference the User primary key.

Comment: my 1st excel table :https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2dDVLVHV4dU1yRFE/edit

Comment: Sorry, no time to look at your postings.  I don't see what Excel has to do with this.  I'm assuming that you're using a real relational database.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a "contact" table with a unique Identifier (either auto increment or a number) and have that unique identifier as a foreign key in your second table

Contact table :
contactID
name
address 
...

Pledge table
pledgeId (primary Key) 
contactID (Foreign key)
Date
...